# Why is Int expected for a function returning (Int,Int)?

Tags: haskell

I have the following code.

```
bar :: (Int, Int)
bar = (1,2) 

foo:: (Int, Int)
foo = do { 
  (n1,n2) <- bar ; 
  (n1,n2) ; 
}
```

The error message:

> Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘(Int, Int)’

Why is `Int` expected at any point? `bar` should evaluate to `(1, 2)`, an instance of `(Int, Int)`, so I was expecting that `n1` and `n2` would be assigned those two values.

If I simplify the do-block to just `do { bar }`, there is no error.

What am I doing wrong?

This is just example code. I need to capture the returned values from `bar`, modify them both, and return a new 2-tuple containing the two modified values.

Comment: Independent of the real issue here: please don't use curly-brace/semicolon syntax unless you have a good reason.

Comment: Neither `bar` nor `int` are functions. They're just tuples. As for `foo`, you need to understand how the `Monad` instance for `(,) a` is defined.

Comment: The `x <- exor` arrow statement in a `do` block is not simple assignment! The thing on the left of the `<-` will never have the same type as the thing on the right.

Answer (score 9):

Don't use `do` notation for stuff where you don't know what monad you're dealing with. Really, before you've properly understood about monads you should perhaps not use it at all for anything other than `IO`.

This error is an artifact of the confusing `Monad (a,)` instance. Your code desugars to

```
foo = bar >>= \(n1,n2) -> (n1,n2)
```

in other words

```
foo = (1,2) >>= id
```

Inline [the definition of `>>=` for tuples](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-479), and we have

```
foo = case id 2 of
  (v,b) -> (1<>v, b)
```

`id 2` is just `2`, so you're trying to match an `Int` against the tuple `(v,b)`.

By contrast, `do {bar}` doesn't actually involve anything monadic at all – it's the same as `bar` all by itself, which of course works fine here. But as you've noticed, the `do` with `<-` does something different.

You *could* also use

```
foo:: (Int, Int)
foo = do
  let (n1,n2) = bar
  (n1,n2)
```

but that should preferrably be written

```
foo = (n1,n2)
 where (n1,n2) = bar
```

Comment: Or `let (n1,n2) = bar in (n1, n2)` or of course `foo = bar` (but that defeats the learning exercise)

Comment: It's not quite right to replace `\(n1,n2) -> (n1,n2)` with `id`. They have different types. The former has type `(a, b) -> (a, b)` and the latter `a -> a`. That means the actual type mismatch happens on `(\(n1, n2) -> (n1, n2)) 2` since `2` does not have type `(a, b)`, whereas with `id` it doesn't happen until matching the `case` statement.